# Kendo Grid filter using checkboxes and mutliple selections

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am using custom multi-select code to filter a column. Currently I can get it to filter based on one selection, but am unable to filter based on multiple values. I need the logic to read, if any of the selected checkboxes are checked, then show the selections in the grid. The way I have it written right now, its filtering each one, but if one of the selections is false, it deletes it from the grid even if one of the other selections are true.

```
var filter = dataSource.filter() || { logic: "or", filters: [] };
            var fieldFilters = $.map(element.find(":checkbox:checked"), function (input) {
                return {
                    field: field,
                    operator: "eq",
                    value: input.value
                };
            });
            if (fieldFilters.length) {
                removeFiltersForField(filter, field);
                filter.filters.push({
                    logic: "or",
                    filters: fieldFilters
                });
                var filterType = filter.filters[0].filters;
                if (filter.filters[0].filters.length > 1) {
                    var filterLogic = { logic: "or", filters: filter.filters };
                    dataSource.filter(filterLogic.filters[0]);
                } else {
                    dataSource.filter(filterType); // This works, but its only one selection
                }

            }
```

I need it to return if any selections are true and ignore the ones that are false. Currently, it goes in order, so if the first selection is true, it shows it in the grid, but if the next one is false, then it removes it from the grid.

Answer (score 0):

OK I was able to make it work doing this. If someone has a more efficient way to do it, add it here. For now, this works:

```
var multipleFilters = [];
                if (filterType.length > 1) {
                    $(filterType).each(function (i, value) {
                        var simpleFilter = { field: value.field, operator: value.operator, value: value.value };
                        multipleFilters.push(simpleFilter);
                    })
                    if (multipleFilters == 2) {
                        dataSource.filter(multipleFilters[0] || multipleFilters[1]);
                    } else if (multipleFilters == 3) {
                        dataSource.filter(multipleFilters[0] || multipleFilters[1] || multipleFilters[2]);
                    } else {
                        dataSource.filter(multipleFilters[1] || multipleFilters[2] || multipleFilters[3]);
                    }
                } else {
                    dataSource.filter(filterType);
                }
```